# Convert JSON string to a list in order to enumerate

Tags: python, json, slack

End goal: I want to get 'userid', 'username', and 'email' from a JSON string that I pulled from Slack. When I try converting it to a list, it only gives me the first three keys, it won't pull the nested data.

Here's my code:

```
    from slackclient._client import SlackClient
    import json

    def main():
       token = "XXXXX"
       sc = SlackClient(token)
       users = get_users(sc)
       print(users)
       print(list(users))

     def get_users(sc):
     print("Get Users")
     print(80 * "=")
     #call the users.list api call and get list of users
     users = (sc.api_call("users.list"))
     users = json.dumps(users)
     users = json.loads(str(users))
     return users

    main()
```

My problem is "print(users)" prints me out an entire JSON string and "print(list(users))" only prints the first un-nested keys. Here's an example of what my output is.

"print(list(users))" gives me the following:

```
    ['members', 'cache_ts', 'ok']
```

"print(users)" gives me the following, but I can't pull anything specific from it as a string.

```
    {'members': [{'real_name': 'XXXXXX', 'is_ultra_restricted': False, 'name': 'XXXXX', 'is_primary_owner': False, 'id': 'XXXXXX', 'color': '4bbe2e', 'status': None, 'profile': {'image_32': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/140a3a97c34e956bb6692fb0f1bd325e.jpg?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F66f9%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0006-32.png', 'real_name': 'XXXXXX', 'first_name': 'XXXXXX', 'avatar_hash': 'g140a3a97c34', 'email': 'XXXXXXX@XXXXX.COM', 'image_192': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/140a3a97c34e956bb6692fb0f1bd325e.jpg?s=192&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F7fa9%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0006-192.png', 'image_24': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/140a3a97c34e956bb6692fb0f1bd325e.jpg?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F66f9%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0006-24.png', 'real_name_normalized': 'XXXXXX', 'image_512': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/140a3a97c34e956bb6692fb0f1bd325e.jpg?s=512&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F7fa9%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0006-512.png', 'last_name': 'XXXXXX', 'image_48': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/140a3a97c34e956bb6692fb0f1bd325e.jpg?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F66f9%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0006-48.png', 'image_72': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/140a3a97c34e956bb6692fb0f1bd325e.jpg?s=72&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F66f9%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0006-72.png'}, 'deleted': False, 'tz': 'America/Los_Angeles', 'tz_offset': -28800, 'is_restricted': False, 'is_admin': False, 'team_id': 'T3854BB3K', 'has_2fa': False, 'is_bot': False, 'tz_label': 'Pacific Standard Time', 'is_owner': False}, {'real_name': 'XXXXXXX, 'is_ultra_restricted': False, 'name': 'XXXXXXX', 'is_primary_owner': True, 'id': 'XXXXXXX', 'color': '9f69e7', 'status': None, 'profile': {'image_32': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/98e886a882b9eb8476b39519a0007b50.jpg?s=32&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F66f9%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0001-32.png', 'real_name': 'XXXXXX', 'first_name': 'XXXXX', 'avatar_hash': 'g98e886a882b', 'email': 'XXXXXXX@gmail.com', 'image_192': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/98e886a882b9eb8476b39519a0007b50.jpg?s=192&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F7fa9%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0001-192.png', 'image_24': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/98e886a882b9eb8476b39519a0007b50.jpg?s=24&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F66f9%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0001-24.png', 'real_name_normalized': 'XXXXXXX', 'image_512': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/98e886a882b9eb8476b39519a0007b50.jpg?s=512&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F7fa9%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0001-512.png', 'last_name': 'XXXXXX', 'image_48': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/98e886a882b9eb8476b39519a0007b50.jpg?s=48&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F0180%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0001-48.png', 'image_72': 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/98e886a882b9eb8476b39519a0007b50.jpg?s=72&d=https%3A%2F%2Fa.slack-edge.com%2F3654%2Fimg%2Favatars%2Fava_0001-72.png'}, 'deleted': False, 'tz': 'America/Chicago', 'tz_offset': -21600, 'is_restricted': False, 'is_admin': True, 'team_id': 'T3854BB3K', 'has_2fa': False, 'is_bot': False, 'tz_label': 'Central Standard Time', 'is_owner': True}, {'real_name': 'Talla', 'is_ultra_restricted': False, 'name': 'talla', 'is_primary_owner': False, 'id': 'XXXXXX', 'color': 'e7392d', 'status': None, 'profile': {'api_app_id': 'A0P3RDP0R', 'image_32': 'https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-11-30/111583483766_0864de31dc83b2d4ad5b_32.png', 'image_original': 'https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-11-30/111583483766_0864de31dc83b2d4ad5b_original.png', 'real_name': 'Talla', 'always_active': False, 'first_name': 'Talla', 'bot_id': 'B38SQ12EN', 'avatar_hash': '0864de31dc83', 'image_1024': 'https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-11-30/111583483766_0864de31dc83b2d4ad5b_512.png', 'image_192': 'https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-11-30/111583483766_0864de31dc83b2d4ad5b_192.png', 'image_24': 'https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-11-30/111583483766_0864de31dc83b2d4ad5b_24.png', 'real_name_normalized': 'Talla', 'image_512': 'https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-11-30/111583483766_0864de31dc83b2d4ad5b_512.png', 'image_48': 'https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-11-30/111583483766_0864de31dc83b2d4ad5b_48.png', 'image_72': 'https://avatars.slack-edge.com/2016-11-30/111583483766_0864de31dc83b2d4ad5b_72.png'}, 'deleted': False, 'tz': None, 'tz_offset': -28800, 'is_restricted': False, 'is_admin': False, 'team_id': 'T3854BB3K', 'is_bot': True, 'tz_label': 'Pacific Standard Time', 'is_owner': False}, {'real_name': 'slackbot', 'is_ultra_restricted': False, 'name': 'slackbot', 'is_primary_owner': False, 'id': 'USLACKBOT', 'color': '757575', 'status': None, 'profile': {'image_32': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/2fac/plugins/slackbot/assets/service_32.png', 'real_name': 'slackbot', 'first_name': 'slackbot', 'fields': None, 'last_name': '', 'image_192': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/66f9/img/slackbot_192.png', 'image_24': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/0180/img/slackbot_24.png', 'real_name_normalized': 'slackbot', 'image_512': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/1801/img/slackbot_512.png', 'avatar_hash': 'sv1444671949', 'image_48': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/2fac/plugins/slackbot/assets/service_48.png', 'image_72': 'https://a.slack-edge.com/0180/img/slackbot_72.png'}, 'deleted': False, 'tz': None, 'tz_offset': -28800, 'is_restricted': False, 'is_admin': False, 'team_id': 'T3854BB3K', 'is_bot': False, 'tz_label': 'Pacific Standard Time', 'is_owner': False}], 'ok': True, 'cache_ts': 1480600947}
```

Comment: The output isn't json, it's Python's representation of a complex dictionary with lists of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

`json.loads()` returns a dictionary, and by default iterating a dictionary is actually iterating over the keys.
try iterating over `users.items()` to get `(key,value)` pairs.

Comment: I tried enumerate and iterate. I'm still only getting the top level.

       enum_users = list(enumerate(users.items(),))

Comment: Tried the iter expression and it turned it into a list for me. Should I just index it?